# Send parameter to server and get return value in NSString format

Tags: ios, json

This is first time I am trying.

Till now I am successful in getting DATA from SERVER in JSON format.

Now what I want to do is,
I have two `NSString` values that I have to send to server and server will check for them.
I don't know what checking mechanism is behind.
I am just sending two strings and server will return me try or false.
And I have to show that true or false thing.

All this will be called onClick of `UIButton`

Here what I tried,

```
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/api/CaptchaImage/CheckCaptchValid?validstring={%@}&encodestring={%@}",string1,string2];

NSMutableURLRequest *req = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [req setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:str]];

    NSURLConnection *connGet = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:req delegate:self];
    if(connGet)
    {
        NSLog(@"Connected successfully");
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Not connected successfully");
    }
```

It gives me NSLog as connected successfully,
But I am struck here,
I want a response from server too in NSString format, either True or False.
Can any one guide me for further steps.

I tried some SO links, but didn't get much.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It doesn't sound like you've done a lot of research and this is not a tutorial site.  Do a search and you will find a lot of code that will make solving your problem fairly easy.

Comment: You need to implement delegate method of `NSURLConnection`

Comment: try to get output of "str" in NSLog? NSLog(@"str %@", str);

Comment: @hemant I tried 
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
to get response, but always failed connection

Comment: Whatever response you want, Need to send it from server side. that means you need to do change in server side, right now you are getting "true" or "false" just because server is sending only Boolean value.

Comment: @ppshein :- I am getting that str in NSLog, but the NSData after response is getting Null

Comment: @sujay :- I only want that true or false value, but I am not getting any value

Comment: @stallone can u show us full code?

Comment: First check your web service on postman or some other tool, if it's working fine or not.

Comment: @Hemant :- yes, its working fine..
I am sending two parameters to web service, and once the service receives those 2 parameters then either I will get True or False.
But I am getting failure in connection to web service only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    [myData appendData:data];
}

-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading: (NSURLConnection *)connection {
    response = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:myData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}
```

Try this, but I have not tested this code. add appropriate delegate method.
Hope this will work for you